# Graphics acceleration (overlay) not working - cannot resize video

Tags: graphics, video, 15.10, vlc, hardware-acceleration

I am following up on my question regarding [missing i915 module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717338/installing-4-4-rc7-kernel-yields-i915-module-not-available).

On my Dell XPS 13 (9350), if I enable the graphics acceleration in VLC (overlay), I cannot resize the video at all, it stays at native size of 1:1 whatever I do (changing window size, full screen, changing zoom etc.). The contextual menu also appear below the video instead of above (so not visible).

I think it is not a VLC issue as I have seen similar behaviours in other programs too.

I am using the released kernel 4.4 on Ubuntu 15.10.

I have installed the Intel driver from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1) and a missing module from [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/sklgucver43). And then I have enabled the Intel driver in the "software source" GUI and rebooted.

Thanks,

Comment: same problem here INTEL i3 (skylake) + Intel B150 chipset with integrated gpu ... VLC canot change video size when resizing window its still 1:1 in the middle of window. But this is propably VLC problem, because GNOME VIDEOS (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos) works fine. ... My OS: UBUNTU GNOME 15.10

Answer (score 2):

I found that a workaround is to install MPV Media Player, and it plays HD videos fullscreen with no chopping.