# Where is skl_guc_ver4.bin?

Tags: kernel

In the kernel source I do see this:

```
drivers/gpu/drm/i915/intel_guc_loader.c
```

I see this define:

```
define I915_SKL_GUC_UCODE "i915/skl_guc_ver4.bin"
```

However, in `lib/firmware` I see:

```
/lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver1_1059.bin
```

It seems linux-firmware doesn't come with the bin file it expects.
Btw, I am running Ubuntu 15.10.
It seems we need to update the linux-firmware package?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and landed here. The solution can be found here: [Installing 4.4 rc7 kernel yields i915 module not available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/717338/installing-4-4-rc7-kernel-yields-i915-module-not-available)

Just execute the following statements:

```
curl -O http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157_all.deb
dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.157_all.deb
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```